# In NestJS, why do objects obtained using TestingModule.get() and EntityManager refer to different entities?

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

**Problem:**

In NestJS, why do objects obtained using TestingModule.get() and EntityManager refer to different entities?

**Context:**

The object obtained with getEntityManagerToken() is a new, unmocked EntityManager.
The object obtained with getRepositoryToken() is a mocked Repository when creating moduleRef.

**Code:**

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getEntityManagerToken, getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';

const mockEntityManager = () => ({
  query: jest.fn(),
  find: jest.fn(),
  findOne: jest.fn(),
});

describe('TEST', () => {
  let sut: Service;
  let replicaRepositoryStub: any;
  let replicaeManagerStub: any;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        Service,
        {
          provide: getEntityManagerToken('replica'),
          useValue: mockEntityManager(),
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Entity, 'replica'),
          useValue: mockEntityManager(),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    sut = moduleRef.get<Service>(Service);
    replicaRepositoryStub = moduleRef.get(getRepositoryToken(Entity, 'replica'));
    replicaeManagerStub = moduleRef.get(getEntityManagerToken('replica'));
  });

  it('test1', async () => {
    replicaRepositoryStub.findOne.mockResolvedValue('test'); // it's ok
    replicaeManagerStub.findOne.mockResolvedValue('test'); // This code causes an error to be thrown.
  });
});
```

**Error Code:**

```
replicaManagerStub.findOne.mockResolvedValue is not a function
TypeError: replicaManagerStub.findOne.mockResolvedValue is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (PATH)
```

**Questions:**

- What is the reason for this discrepancy?
- Is it possible to get EntityManager through moduleRef?
- If so, how can it be done?

I have tried various approaches to solve this issue and confirmed that the object obtained through moduleRef returns a new EntityManager.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I imported the TypeORM module while creating a test module. Therefore, I assumed that a new entity manager was created when I got the entity manager from the moduleRef, and I solved the issue by removing the relevant part.